# Javascript: How to Iterate Through An Array, Moving Last Item to First Item Each Time

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

New to JavaScript. I am trying to iterate through an array, removing the last item and adding it as the new first item each time, and console-logging the new array after each loop. For example, if I start with this array:

`['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

The next array would look like this:

`['5', '1', '2', '3', '4']`

And then this:

`['4', '5', '1', '2', '3']`

Etc. until the array essentially returns back to the original `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`.

I tried this:

```
newArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] 
  console.log(newArray)

newArray.forEach(function() { 
  lastItem = newArray[-1];     // Define "lastItem" as the value of the last item in the array
  newArray.pop();              // Remove the last item from the array
  newArray.unshift(lastItem);  // Add the value of "lastItem" to the front of the array
  console.log(newArray); 
});
```

This seemed to be the right track, as JS attempted to remove my last item and add it to the front each time. However, the new front item returned as "undefined" each time, like this:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
[undefined, "1", "2", "3", "4"]
[undefined, undefined, "1", "2", "3"]
[undefined, undefined, undefined, "1", "2"]
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "1"]
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Why isn't JS recognizing my `lastItem` as the value in the [-1] field from the array each time it loops through? Should I be going about this differently?

Comment: Because you can't get last item like that using negative index. Instead the return value of pop will give you last item.

Comment: `newArray[-1]` -> `newArray[newArray.length-1]`. Negative indeces will not loop around, they just give you the item at that index and that index doesn't exist. So you get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```js
newArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] 

newArray.forEach(function() { 
  newArray.push(newArray.shift());
  console.log(newArray)
});
```

newArray.push(...) is adding a new value to the back

newArray.shift() removes the first element of the array but returns its value first.

Comment: Thank you! While your code did the opposite of what I was trying (it took the first item and moved it to the back, instead of the back item and moved it to the front), your concept is what I used to get mine to work! Here's how I ended up writing it (sorry, not sure how to format code in comments):

`newArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
console.log(newArray)
newArray.forEach(function() {
newArray.unshift(newArray.pop());
console.log(newArray)
});`

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you should never iterate over a mutating array, otherwise you will end up having problems.
For the problem of moving last item to be the first one I would go with a functional approach.

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5];

function rotate(ar) {
    return [
        ar[ar.length -1],
        ...ar.slice(0, -1)
    ];
}

const iteration1 = rotate(data);
const iteration2 = rotate(iteration1);
console.log(iteration1)
console.log(iteration2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me! Being new to JS I did not even know that 'rotate' existed.

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist. You have to create it yourself in order to use it.

Comment: Omg duh, I didn't realize you'd created it yourself. :facepalm:

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Several working solutions were offered, but here was the solution with the least amount of code:

```
newArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] 
  console.log(newArray)
newArray.forEach(function() {
  newArray.unshift(newArray.pop());
  console.log(newArray)
});
```

This correctly brings back the following in the console log:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
["5", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
["4", "5", "1", "2", "3"]
["3", "4", "5", "1", "2"]
["2", "3", "4", "5", "1"]
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try using `array[array.length - 1]` as **the last element** , Index `-1` and negative indexes are undefined in JS as you can see

> JavaScript arrays are collections of items, where each item is accessible through an index. These indexes are non-negative integers, and accessing a negative index will just return undefined

***Note***  :If you are persistent to use negative indexes for some reason you can define a `Proxy`

```
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const proxy = new Proxy(letters, {
    get(target, prop) {
        if (!isNaN(prop)) {
            prop = parseInt(prop, 10);
            if (prop < 0) {
                prop += target.length;
            }
        }
        return target[prop];
    }
});
proxy[0]; // => 'a'
proxy[-1]; // => 'e'
proxy[-2]; // => 'd'
```

This [Medium article](https://medium.com/uncaught-exception/javascript-array-negative-index-using-proxies-ed096dc84416#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20arrays%20are%20collections%20of,index%20will%20just%20return%20undefined%20.) explains more about this

Comment: Thank you! Having learned Python just before JS, I was so used to using the [0], [-1] indexing in JS as well. Didn't realize it doesn't work the same way. >_<